# Make HTTP request with explicitly invalid request path

Tags: python, http, python-requests

Normally, when sending a HTTP request, the actually traffic is like below:

```
GET /abc?hello HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: python-requests/2.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
```

However, I would like to send URLs without the leading slash, for example:

```
GET abc?hello HTTP/1.1

GET ftp://abc?hello HTTP/1.1
```

I understand that's not compliant with RFCs, but just need to send such request for testing purpose in Python.

Have checked requests, urllib, urllib2, urllib3, haven't figured out how to do it.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Most HTTP libraries try to be .. compliant. Regardless, since HTTP is just a text protocol, it can be easily emulated insofar as sending “bad requests” - just so so at a sub-HTTP (eg. “telnet”) level to avoid (sane) enforcement of compliance by the library.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @robinsax For testing purpose, need to test how a server respond for all kinds of weird requests.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks, that's probably the direction I should go. Will see if I can use Python to create SSL socket, and then send such requests.